# Kotlin -Run print statement when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, printf, android-button

I'm a `Swift` dev and I'm just getting into `Kotlin` so I'm unfamiliar with how things work.

In `Swift` if I create a button and add an action/target to it, and in that action I add a `print statement` it gets printed out in the console.

```
lazy var myButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    // create button
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func myButtonPressed() {
    print("this gets printed to the console")
}
```

But in `Kotlin` when I had a `print statement` nothing gets printed to the `Build Output` nor the `Event Log`

```
val myButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.myButtonId)
myButton.setOnClickListener { myButtonPressed() }

private fun myButtonPressed() {
    print("nothing gets printed to the console, I have to use the Toast function")
}
```

[image]

I have to use

```
private fun myButtonPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "this briefly appears inside the emulator", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this the way it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add to use `Log.d()` and I had to run it in `Debug mode`:

```
import android.util.Log // *** 1. include this import statement ***

private val TAG = "MainActivity" // *** 2. add this constant, name it TAG and set the value to the name of the Activity ***

val myButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.myButtonId)
myButton.setOnClickListener { myButtonPressed() }

private fun myButtonPressed() {

    Log.d(TAG, ">>>>> now this prints to the console <<<<<<") // *** 3. add the TAG inside the first param inside the Log.d statement ***
}
```

[image]